# XLForm formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged not working

Tags: ios

I'm using XLForm and Objective-C (not Swift).

I can't trigger `formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged:` no matter what my if else conditions are. I placed the code in my .m file. Any reason why I can't get it to work?

I copied the example code exactly and modified it according to my needs. However, no matter how I try, nothing is invoked. Does it matter that I created the form in `viewDidLoad`? Please advise.

Thank you in advance to all you pros!

Here's the example code:

```
-(void)formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)rowDescriptor oldValue:(id)oldValue newValue:(id)newValue
{
[super formRowDescriptorValueHasChanged:rowDescriptor oldValue:oldValue newValue:newValue]; 
if ([rowDescriptor.tag isEqualToString:@"alert"]){
    if ([[rowDescriptor.value valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(0)] == NO && [[oldValue valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(0)]){
        XLFormRowDescriptor * newRow = [rowDescriptor copy];
        [newRow setTag:@"secondAlert"];
        newRow.title = @"Second Alert";
        [self.form addFormRow:newRow afterRow:rowDescriptor];
    }
    else if ([[oldValue valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(0)] == NO && [[newValue valueData] isEqualToNumber:@(0)]){
        [self.form removeFormRowWithTag:@"secondAlert"];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'm still too new to all these, but a bit of trial and error here and there solved it. I believe that since I did the form in `viewDidLoad`, there is a need to set `self.form.delegate = self;`

All is well now. Thanks for the attempt @Shams Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming you haven't made your view controller a subclass of `XLFormViewController`. if you did `XLFormDescriptor` delegate would have set for you.

if you not using that approach make sure your `XLFormDescriptor` object has set its delegate to your view controller.

Comment: I have already subclassed my view controller properly. I can trigger other methods such as `didSelectFormRow:` though..